# Flask-SQLAlchemy Single Table Inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, flask-sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy support [single table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#single-inheritance).

I have structure like:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_user'
    type = db.Column(db.String(32)) 
    ...
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'user',
        'polymorphic_on': type,
        'with_polymorphic': '*'
    }

class Tourist(User):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'tourist'
    }
    ...

class Guide(User):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'guide'
    }
    ...
```

When I try to run code, i get error like:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'tbl_user' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

When I add 'extend_existing' as table property:

```
__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
```

Then I get next error when I try anything with model mentioned:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'tbl_user' and 'tbl_user'.
```

This should be something straight forward, and should be solvable by single attribute, especially that it is working fine with SQLAlchemy.
Any ideas how to solve problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found a way how mentioned should work. I need to remove `with_polymorfic` option from initial mapper args and to add `__tablename__ = None` for children classes, so exact code look like:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_user'
    type = db.Column(db.String(32)) 
    ...
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'user',
        'polymorphic_on': type,
    }  # remove with_polymorphic

class Tourist(User):
    __tablename__ = None  # Add table name to be None
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'tourist'
    }
    ...

class Guide(User):
    __tablename__ = None  # Add table name to be None
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'guide'
    }
    ...
```