# SQLAlchemy Single Table Inheritance with polymorphic_identity lacks WHERE

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The situation:
I have one data table 'my_table' with several columns (lets call them 'a', 'b' and 'c').

Using SQLAlchemy I've created 3 classes within my model:

```
class MyTableBase():
     a = Column(int)

class MyClassOne(MyTableBase):
     b = Column(int)

class MyObjectTwo(MyTableBase):
     c = Column(int)
```

I want to override default *query(MyClassOne).all()* to return only records with a=10 and query(MyClassTwo).all() to return only records with a=20.

That should provide quite elegant way to store many different (but very similar) kinds of objects in one table while playing with them separately at the class/object level.

Any suggestions? Maybe it's my lack of searching skills but simply can't find it :/

**Update**:

My code now:

```
class MyTableBase: 
    __tablename__ = u'my_table_base'
    a = Column(VARCHAR(length=20)) #to distinct different types
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": a} 

class MyClassOne(MyTableBase): 
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "aaaa"} 
    b = Column(int)

class MyClassTwo(MyTableBase): 
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "bbbb"} 
    c = Column(int)
```

My DB table has two records - one has the value of "aaaa" and the other "bbbb" in the "a" column. Query for MyClassOne and MyClassTwo returns both rows. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:
To select the data I do use:

```
cls_query = Session.query(MyClassOne)
print 'cls_query: ',cls_query
cls_query.all()
```

The print result is:

```
cls_query: SELECT my_table_base.id AS my_table_base_id,
my_table_base.a AS my_table_base_a,
my_table_base.b AS my_table_base_b
FROM my_table_base
```

Please notice it's taking only columns from required class MyClassOne (column c is not present in the SELECT statement), but still it lacks WHERE part.

Comment: Use `a` as the discriminator column, as described in [Mapping Class Inheritance Hierarchies](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html). What you're trying to do looks like [single table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance).

Comment: Can you show the code you are actually using to insert and pull the rows out of the table, and the actual models? For starters, MyTableBase.a is defined as an integer but your polymorphic identities are Strings. If you want to define MyClassOne to be all records in your table with a=10 then your polymorphic_identity for that model should be 10.

Comment: This part is fine. var a is now a Column(VARCHAR(length=20)) - it's my mistake here when shortening the source code. All I do is cls_query = Session.query(MyClassA). It returns correct SQL but unfortunately without WHERE a = identity_value.

Comment: Please check the update. Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you please supply a full MCVE?    e.g. your query is against nonexistent class "MyObjectOne".   a single-table inheritance query against a subclass will automatically add the WHERE clause.  if you are not seeing that, need complete runnable demonstration.

Comment: Right - just corrected it. It was my typing mistake. What's even more interesting making an INSERT using MyClassOne or MyClassTwo automatically puts appropriate value to the discriminator column. But still no WHERE clause during SELECT. Will try to prepare MCVE as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

As found in here: 
[Flask-SQLAlchemy Single Table Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782907/flask-sqlalchemy-single-table-inheritance)

The correct answer is **__tablename__ = None** in all subclasses.

```
class MyTableBase: 
    __tablename__ = u'my_table_base'
    a = Column(VARCHAR(length=20)) #to distinct different types
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": a} 

class MyClassOne(MyTableBase):
    __tablename__ = None
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "aaaa"} 
    b = Column(int)

class MyClassTwo(MyTableBase): 
    __tablename__ = None
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "bbbb"} 
    c = Column(int)
```

This information is not present in the relevant SQLAlchemy docs :(

Works fine now!

Comment: It's described here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_mixins.html#controlling-table-inheritance-with-mixins and there is also another way to do it using `@declared_attr`